# Category tree is flattened inside admin upon saving

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

Is there a way to avoid WordPress "flattening" the category tree when a child category is selected?

This applies to both custom taxonomies and WP's built in "category" taxonomy.

To explain further, say I have the following category tree:

```
Parent
    Child
        Grandchild
Another parent
    Another child
    Another child
A third parent
```

If I then select "Grandchild" as my category, the tree will now look like this upon saving:

```
Grandchild
Parent
    Child
Another parent
    Another child
    Another child
A third parent
```

This makes it very hard for authors to remember which grandchild belongs to which parent and imo makes absolutely zero sense. I guess one reason for this might be so that the selected category is always in the top of the list, but I would very much like to disable this behaviour.

Also see attached image.

[image: Flattened Categories]

Please note that this is not theme or plugin-related. I tried this with a completely fresh WP-install with zero plugins and the default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't fully tested this, but it may be helpful:
Categories in Hierarchical Order plugin at https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-in-hierarchical-order/

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I tried Googling myself first of course, but I guess I phrased my query poorly because I couldn't find a thing.

Comment: This plugin works well, thank you! With issues like this it is difficult to know what to search for. I searched for 'category moves from parent on save wordpress'.

Answer (score 5):

The plugin can be resumed to this simple code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', function( $args ) {
    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    return $args;
});
```